# How can I show HTML page in Power BI

Tags: html, powerbi, powerbi-desktop, power-bi-report-server, powerbi-custom-visuals

I need to show an *HTML page* in a *Power BI visual*. I tried the *HTML Viewer Custom Visual* from the AppViewer, but my page is heavy. I also tried to include my HTML code in a Power BI dashboard through a tile, but again there are too many elements in my page.

Do you know a way to show the page inside Power BI reports?

I also tried pbiviz through `npm` without success.

Comment: any luck on the solution part ????

Comment: @qaiser unfortunately not